# Merge one feature branch to another

Tags: eclipse, git, git-merge

I have two feature branches.

`Branch1` and `Branch2`, and I want to merge Branch1 to Branch2 in eclipse.

But am getting conflicts.

Not able to find any working solution.

Can anyone please help me  ?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you need to resolve the conflicts. A conflict happens when git can't figure out what to do by itself and needs your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Please post the error. With no details it's hard to answer your question.
If you have conflicts check your files it may have `<<<HEAD` which is the conflict marker.
After you solve the conflicts commit your changes and then try to merge again.

Comment: After you solve your conflicts, you add them to index, then run `git merge --continue`, no need to merge _again_, just in case.

Comment: @eftshift0 The question is about Git via Eclipse, not Git via the command line (which may not even be installed).